# Django: how to set the path for the environ variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"

Tags: django

In Django, I used to write populating scripts and put them in the project root directory. For example,

```
mysite/
    mysite/
    manage.py
    populateA.py
```

The first few lines of `populateA.py`:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
import django
django.setup()

...
```

As there are more and more populating scripts, I would like to move them to another package `populate`:

```
mysite/
    mysite/
    manage.py
    populate/
        __init__.py
        populateA.py
        populateB.py
        populateC.py
        ...
```

However, when I run the populating scripts (`python populateA.py`), I got the error message: `ImportError: No module named 'mysite'`. How to properly set the path for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `populate` is already a module, run its submodules.

```
python -m populate.populateA
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.